# Firing destroy without creating an isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Use Case

The application I'm working on is fairly dynamic. Inputs change dynamically based on a template variable. The directive I have, based on a variety of scope variables, will grab the necessary templates and build the html output. Events are also associated with each of these templates and so the childScope needs to be destroyed in order to fire the appropriate destroy events when the scope changes. In particular, I found that if I don't call the destroy method, a memory leak will occur.

[edits]
To expand the definition further, essentially we have a generic widget. For people that can see a button is rendered that changes value based on the number of times it is clicked. For the visually impaired, this button is rendered as a list of radio buttons. The buttons are essentially "hotspots" rendered on top of an image. This is used to evaluate pain scores on joints. However, visually impaired patients can't see the buttons, but the screen reader can read out the radio inputs. A tablet is used for data capturing and passed between researcher, patient and doctor. A toggle button will switch between visual mode and visually impaired mode as it is quicker for the doctors to comprehend the image view. WiFi is an issue as connection in the hospital is spotty, so I used angular to make a SPA for this.

So how it works is there is a variable called template which is passed into the directive. The link will read this variable and load the appropriate templates which is cached. When the button is pressed, template may change and the link will re-read this. The issue I found is that the jQuery slider will cause a memory leak when I switch it from a slider to a radio list input for the visually impaired. The more times the view is switched, the more memory is consumed. However, if the destroy method is called before the $compile, the memory leak issue disappears. Unfortunately, calling scope.$destroy destroys everything, so a childScope was used to prevent this.

This could be completed using ng-if or ng-switch on the template variable, however, we took the programmatic route because essentially, a requirement that is coming up is that these widget should change dynamically in multiple views. Currently we only have visual and visually impaired mode, but they also want it to have "doctor view", "researcher view", "patient view", "patient visually impaired view", "elderly view", etc... Depending on the view, the widget will change its appearance and functionality. i.e. some views may have additional behaviours.

### Problem

I'm unable to bind the model to the generated childScope. I think the fundamental problem is the **$new()** creates an isolated scope, so I suspect that it can't communicate with the outside world. However, what I really want to do is destroy the scope properly to avoid the memory leak.

My question is:

- Is there a way to have the childScope bind with the parent ng-model?
- Is there a another method to fire destroy?

### Code

Here is a stripped down and simplified version of my non-working code. I've removed most of the complexity to reduce it down to the fundamental components.

#### Template

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div>
        <h1>Input</h1>
        <doodad ng-model="foo"></doodad>
        <nested-doodad ng-model="bar"></nested-doodad>
        <nested-doodad ng-model="qux.value"></nested-doodad>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Output</h1>
        <span>{{ foo }}</span>
        <span>{{ bar }}</span>
        <span>{{ qux | json }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Application

```
    function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "foo";
    $scope.bar = "bar";
    $scope.qux = { value : "qux" };
}
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('doodad', function($compile) {
      var linker = function(scope, element) {
          var childScope;

          /* Used to fire destroy on child widgets */
          var getNewScope = function(oldScope) {
            if (oldScope) {
                oldScope.$destroy();
                oldScope = null;
                element.html('');
            }
            return scope.$new();
          };

          var renderTemplate = function() {
              childScope = getNewScope(childScope);
              /* template is dynamic - hardcoded for example */
              /* events & lots of other funny stuff are bound here */
              element.html('<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" />');
              $compile(element.contents())(childScope);
          }

          scope.$watch('template', renderTemplate);
      }
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          require: '^ngModel',
          scope: {
              ngModel : '=',
              template: '='
          },
          link: linker
      }
  })
  .directive('nestedDoodad', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          scope: {
              ngModel : "="
          },
          template: '<div><doodad ng-model="ngModel"></doodad></div>'
      }
  });
```

### JSFiddles

- [Non-working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/s3Cdv/5/)
- [Working Example without the childScope](http://jsfiddle.net/s3Cdv/3/)

Comment: Why are you trying to create a child scope? Also, this example could be done entirely in the directive's template. What problem are you trying to solve by modifying the DOM yourself instead of letting Angular do this for you?

Comment: @Jonathan Updated use case above to expand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have the childScope bind with the parent ng-model?

```
$scope = $parent.$scope;
```

> Is there a another method to fire destroy?

```
angular.element(document).injector().get('$rootElement').removeClass("ng-scope")
```

**References**

- [AngularJS: Developer Guide: Working With CSS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/css-styling)